# How to preserve source text in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I realize that this is probably a very basic question but I've already tried searching the web without much effect.

I need to summarize my findings into a report, so I open an RStudio, click "file" and then "R markdown...". I name my report "test", choose HTML and get to the default R Markdown document:

```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this: 
[...]
```

I then try to knit the default document and export is to HTML. I try this and get a decent output. The source code however gets converted into several pages' worth of HTML gibberish:

```
<title>test</title>

<script>/*! jQuery v1.11.3 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(a,b){var c=[],d=c.slice,e=c.concat,f=c.push,g=c.indexOf,h={},i=h.toString,j=h.hasOwnProperty,k={},l="1.11.3",m=function(a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)},n=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,o=/^-ms-/,p=/-([\da-z])/gi,q=function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()};m.fn=m.prototype={jquery:l,constructor:m,selector:"",length:0,toArray:function(){return d.call(this)},get:function(a){return null!=a?0>a?this[a+this.length]:this[a]:d.call(this)},pushStack:function(a){var b=m.merge(this.constructor(),a);return b.prevObject=this,b.context=this.context,b},each:function(a,b){return m.each(this,a,b)},map:function(a){return this.pushStack(m.map(this,function(b,c){return a.call(b,c,b)}))},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(d.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},eq:function(a){var b=this.length,c=+a+(0>a?b:0);return this.pushStack(c>=0&&b>c?[this[c]]:[])},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor(null)},push:f,sort:c.sort,splice:c.splice},m.extend=m.fn.extend=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=arguments[0]||{},h=1,i=arguments.length,j=!1;for("boolean"==typeof g&&(j=g,g=arguments[h]||{},h++),"object"==typeof g||m.isFunction(g)||(g={}),h===i&&(g=this,h--);i>h;h++)if(null!=(e=arguments[h]))for(d in e)a=g[d],c=e[d],g!==c&&(j&&c&&(m.isPlainObject(c)||(b=m.isArray(c)))?(b?(b=!1,f=a&&m.isArray(a)?a:[]):f=a&&m.isPlainObject(a)?a:{},g[d]=m.extend(j,f,c)):void 0!==c&&(g[d]=c));return g},m.extend({expando:"jQuery"+(l+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),isReady:!0,error:function(a){throw new Error(a)},noop:function(){},isFunction:function(a){return"function"===m.type(a)},isArray:Array.isArray||function(a){return"array"===m.type(a)},isWindow:function(a){return null!=a&&a==a.window},isNumeric:function(a){return!m.isArray(a)&&a-parseFloat(a)+1>=0},isEmptyObject:function(a){var b;for(b in a)return!1;return!0},isPlainObject:function(a){var b;if(!a||"object"!==m.type(a)||a.nodeType||m.isWindow(a))return!1;try{if(a.constructor&&!j.call(a,"constructor")&&!j.call(a.constructor.prototype,"isPrototypeOf"))return!1}catch(c){return!1}if(k.ownLast)for(b in a)return j.call(a,b);for(b in a);return void 0===b||j.call(a,b)},type:function(a){return null==a?a+"":"object"==typeof a||"function"==typeof a?h[i.call(a)]||"object":typeof a},globalEval:function(b){b&&m.trim(b)&&(a.execScript||function(b){a.eval.call(a,b)})(b)},camelCase:function(a){return a.replace(o,"ms-").replace(p,q)},nodeName:function(a,b){return a.nodeName&&a.nodeName.toLowerCase()===b.toLowerCase()},each:function(a,b,c){var d,e=0,f=a.length,g=r(a);if(c){if(g){for(;f>e;e++)if(d=b.apply(a[e],c),d===!1)break}else for(e in a)if(d=b.apply(a[e],c),d===!1)break}else if(g){for(;f>e;e++)if(d=b.call(a[e],e,a[e]),d===!1)break}else for(e in a)if(d=b.call(a[e],e,a[e]),d===!1)break;return a},tri
```

As stated, this is probably a stupid question but how on earth do I get the original source code back so I can keep editing the document?

Answer (score -1):

When you press "knit" you're taken to a dialog box where you're asked to provide the file name. Apparantly the source code turns to gibberish if you save the output explicitly as an HTML file. If you don't provide a file ending (but have HTML as the default output format) the source code will remain the same and you can keep on editing.

Comment: The suitable extension for an R markdown file is *.Rmd. You don't save the output explicitly, you just save the R markdown file.